# Latex - can't left align equation written as array in enumeration environment

Tags: math-mode

I'm trying to create a solution sheet to show steps used in solving a systems of equations problems using the equal values method.

Thanks to SE Bernard, I have successfully created all the steps to solve the system of equations.

One small prob...

Starting in line #25 ("5 = 3x - 9) the alignment on the equal sign shifts instead of the "=" staying vertically in line with the previous step, also "5 = 3x - 9".

How can I preserve the vertical alignment of the "=" through each section of the solution steps?

BTW: I used the array because I couldn't find a better method of showing subtraction in a vertical stack. Is there better way to achieve this "stacking" of the equations?

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, amsmath,booktabs}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=20mm,
 top=20mm,
 }
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item $y=2x+5$s\\$y=5x-9$

  \setlength{\parskip}{14pt}

 $\begin{alignedat}{3}
 2x & +{} & 5 &= & & 5x-9 \\
 -2x & & & = {}& - & 2x\\
 \midrule
  & &5 & = & & 3x-9
 \end{alignedat}$

\setlength{\parskip}{14pt}

$\begin{alignedat}{3}
5 & = & & 3x-9 \\ 
    + 9 & ={}{}& &{}+9\\ \midrule 14 & = & & 3x 
    \end{alignedat}$
\setlength{\parskip}{14pt}

$\begin{alignedat}{3}\dfrac{5}{3}  = \dfrac{3x}{3} 
     \end{alignedat}$

\setlength{\parskip}{14pt}

$\dfrac{5}{3}=x$

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

My code is below. Thanks for your help! My students will benefit immensely from properly typeset solution keys.

Comment: if you get a tex error, ask about the error, don't even look at the pdf output which is not intended to be usable. The above produces `! Paragraph ended before \flalign* was complete.` You can not have a blank line, or `\[` inside `flalign`

Comment: Your prob #1 is not clear to me. In which equations should there be an alignment of the – sign?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For what I've understood, it is easily done with `alignedat`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, amsmath,booktabs}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=20mm,
 top=20mm,
 }

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item $y=2x+5$s\\$y=5x-9$\\


 $\begin{alignedat}{3}
 2x & +{} & 5 &= & & 5x-9 \\
 -2x & & & = {}& - & 2x\\
 \midrule
  & &5 & = & & 3x-9
 \end{alignedat}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit*: Here is a code that satisfies the final requirements of the O.P.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, mathtools, booktabs}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=20mm,
 top=20mm,
 }
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item $y=2x+5$s\\$y=5x-9$

 $\begin{alignedat}{4}
 2x &&{}+ 5 &= & & 5x- & & 9 \\
 -2x & & & = -& & 2x\\
 \midrule
 & &5 & = & & 3x-{} & & 9 \\
\addlinespace[14pt]
 & & 5 & = & & 3x -{}& & 9 \\
&&{} +9 & =& &&\mathllap{{}+{}} &9\\\midrule%%
 & & 14 & = & & 3x \\
\addlinespace[14pt]
%%$\begin{alignedat}{3}
 & & \dfrac{5}{3} & = & & \dfrac{3x}{3}\\
\addlinespace[14pt]
 & & \dfrac{5}{3} & = & & \phantom{3}x
     \end{alignedat}$

\end{enumerate}
```

[image]

Comment: Bernard's alignedat works brilliantly. Is there a way to tweak the alignment so that the minus (subtraction) sign doesn't shift the -2x out of alignment with the 5x above. Because I can't figure out how to upload an image from dropbox (my school district blocks access to imgur) here's a link to an image to show the situation. PS. Kudos Bernard & David!  https://www.dropbox.com/s/nmw9h8bb1vw8d2b/array%20alignment%20minor%20tweak.png?dl=0

Comment: @WyoWindStorm: I've added a third column in `alignedat`. Is the result like you want?

Comment: Awesome!!! Many thanks! One strange wrinkle.... To create the 2nd step of the solution process I copied this line  
"$\begin{alignedat}{3}
  & &5 & = & & 3x-9 \\
 
expecting the formatting to be duplicated. 

Instead the "5 =" shifted left and the "3x-9" shifted right. 

Here's the code for step 2 of the solution:

$\begin{alignedat}{3}
  & &5 & = & & 3x-9 \\
 -2x & & & +9=  - & 2x\\
 \midrule
  & &&5 & = & & 3x-9
 \end{alignedat}$

Comment: I've made a correction in the code( the spacing of the + in the first aligned equation was nos good). For you step 2, two alignment columns are enough. Try this code, if I understand what you'd like: `$\begin{alignedat}{2}5 & = & & 3x-9 \\ -2x +9 & ={} & - & 2x\\ \midrule5 & = & & 3x-9 \end{alignedat}$`

Comment: Perfect. Thank you! Given the complexity (for me) of the array code in terms of creating desired alignment, is there a better solution for creating the solution steps? Somewhere read about a package called "systeme". Is there a LaTeX package specifically designed for this?

Comment: It is a LaTeX package that I tried, with indeed a simple syntax, but I could not realise all you requirements – it makes the alignment for the left-hand side, but we could tweek it to obtain the alignment on the r.h.s. (at least for this one), and above all I don't see how to add a horizontal rule.

Comment: The code above now includes every step to solve for "x". Would like to have all the steps align on the "=" sign. Tried inserting extra & and playing with {alignedat}{values} ...all to no avail.

Comment: @WyoWindStorm/ I've posted a code with every step aligned. It uses 4 alignment columns and `mathtools`.

Comment: Bravo, SE'r Bernard! Beautiful rendering!